# why my rule can not fire? how to make it?

Tags: clips

```
(defrule myrule
(and
    (s  (time 1803))
    (f1 (start ?s1))
    (f2 (start ?s2))
    (f3 (start ?s3))
)
=>
if(< ?s1 7)
    then 
    (bind ?s1 (+ ?s1 24))
if(< ?s2 7)
    then 
    (bind ?s2 (+ ?s2 24))
if(< ?s3 7)
    then 
    (bind ?s3 (+ ?s3 24))
if(or (> ?s1 ?s2) (> ?s2 ?s3)(> ?s1 ?s3))
    then
    (assert 0015)))
)
```

i guess ,maybe the RHS don't run sequentially.but how should i make it?
then i changed my way like this:

```
 (deffunction time-24 (?w1)
   (if(< ?w1 7)
   then
   (bind ?w1 (+ ?w1 24))
   )

   )

(defrule myrule
(and
    (s  (time 1803))
    (f1 (start ?s1))
    (f2 (start ?s2))
    (f3 (start ?s3))
    (time-24 ?s1)
    (time-24 ?s2)
    (time-24 ?s3)
)
=>
(if(or (> ?s1 ?s2) (> ?s2 ?s3)(> ?s1 ?s3))
    then
    (assert 0015))
)
```

and finaly,it did't fire too,so there must be something wrong,or maybe there is another way.

Answer (score 0):

don't use `(and)` inside your rule, it's not needed.

```
(defrule myrule
    (s  (time 1803))
    (f1 (start ?s1))
    (f2 (start ?s2))
    (f3 (start ?s3))
=>  ...)
```

And look at your synthax, you have written two more parenthesis ))

```
  (defrule myrule (and
        (s  (time 1803))
        (f1 (start ?s1))
        (f2 (start ?s2))
        (f3 (start ?s3)) )
    => if(< ?s1 7)
        then 
        (bind ?s1 (+ ?s1 24)) if(< ?s2 7)
        then 
        (bind ?s2 (+ ?s2 24)) if(< ?s3 7)
        then 
        (bind ?s3 (+ ?s3 24)) if(or (> ?s1 ?s2) (> ?s2 ?s3)(> ?s1 ?s3))
        then
        (assert 0015)    ))  ;remove these 2 parenthesis 
     )
```

Bye

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous syntax errors in your code. Corrected code is:

```
CLIPS> (deftemplate s (slot time))
CLIPS> (deftemplate f1 (slot start))
CLIPS> (deftemplate f2 (slot start))
CLIPS> (deftemplate f3 (slot start))
CLIPS> 
(deffacts start
  (s (time 1803))
  (f1 (start 9)) 
  (f2 (start 8))
  (f3 (start 4)))
CLIPS> 
(deffunction time-24 (?w1)
  (if (< ?w1 7)
     then
     (return (+ ?w1 24))
     else
     (return ?w1)))
CLIPS> 
(defrule myrule
  (and (s  (time 1803))
       (f1 (start ?s1))
       (f2 (start ?s2))
       (f3 (start ?s3)))
  =>
  (bind ?s1 (time-24 ?s1))
  (bind ?s2 (time-24 ?s2))
  (bind ?s3 (time-24 ?s3))
  (if (or (> ?s1 ?s2) 
          (> ?s2 ?s3)
          (> ?s1 ?s3))
     then
     (assert (F0015))))
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (agenda)
0      myrule: f-1,f-2,f-3,f-4
For a total of 1 activation.
CLIPS> (run)
CLIPS> (facts)
f-0     (initial-fact)
f-1     (s (time 1803))
f-2     (f1 (start 9))
f-3     (f2 (start 8))
f-4     (f3 (start 4))
f-5     (F0015)
For a total of 6 facts.
CLIPS>
```